# Best practice, or generally best way to set up web-hosting server, permissions, etc

Tags: apache-2.2, linux, web-server

I'm about to set up a server upon which a friend and I will be hosting web sites, and I'll be using Debian.  I've set up a LAMP solution many times just to using for local testing purposes, but never for actual production use.

I was wondering what are the best practices are in terms of setting the server up, in reference specifically to accessing the web root directory.  A couple of the options I have seen:

- Set up a single user account on the server for us both to use and use a virtual host to point to the somewhere in the home directory, e.g. /home/webdev/www.
- Set each of us up a user account, and grant permissions in some way to /var/www (What would be the best way?  Set up a new group?)

I want to get this right when I first set this up as there won't be any going back for a while once our first site is up and running.

Appreciate any guidance in advance.

Answer (score 4):

[HERE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/77/apache-server-hardening) is a link from a sister site, with a pretty good coverage of topics.

Answer (score 0):

Create separate user accounts for both of you, and make sure the files are in the same group as the webserver. (i.e. option 2).

Neither option is really best practice. What you really should be doing is using a version control system such as subversion (SVN), each working on a separate branch, and merging your changes together ('trunk'). A service such as beanstalk can help you get off the ground quickly. (www.beanstalkapp.com)